# How can I swap a servo with a stepper motor?

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, servo, stepper

I'm looking for a way to swap servo 1 with a stepper motor to achieve a single direction circular motion with stops and delay. Instead, now I have the servo going back and forth to repeat the action.

[image]

This is the code I'm currently using to drive the servo:

```
void loop() {
  topServo.write(115);
  delay(500);

  for(int i = 115; i > 65; i--) {
    topServo.write(i);
    delay(2);
}
```

This is a schematic of my project:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT9MCD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can anyone help me to configure this? or point me into the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you got the 28-BYJ48 stepper motor, did you also get a ULN2003  Motor driver board?

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, I do have a ULN2003 Motor driver board

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'm going to assume that you got a ULN2003 Motor driver board something like [this](http://42bots.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/stepper01.jpg) along with your 28-BYJ48 stepper motor.

Secondly, I would always recommend using a separate power supply for your stepper motors. Even a small stepper motor like the 28-BYJ48 can draw up to 320mA, (160mA per winding).

---

I've used the following code to test a setup using a 28-BYJ48 stepper motor and an Arduino. The connections to the driver board (IN1 - IN4) are mapped to pins 8-11 on the Arduino in this case. The code will cause the stepper to rotate 1 full revolution in one direction, pause for 1 second and then rotate one full revolution in the other direction.

(I've often found this simple piece of code really handy for troubleshooting!)

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRev = 2048

// initialise the stepper library on pins 8, 9, 10 & 11
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRev, 8,10,9,11);        

void setup() {
  // set the speed
  myStepper.setSpeed(4);

}

void loop() {
  // step one revolution in one direction:
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRev);
  delay(1000);

  // step one revolution in the other direction:
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRev);
  delay(1000); 

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will give this a try. Is it mandatory to use a separate power supply for the stepper motor? I don't think it's drawing that much current. Or do you recommend this for other reasons? I don't have an extra power adapter laying around to test this at the moment. Could I use a battery instead?

Comment: A suitable battery will work fine, but even a small stepper motor like the 28-BYJ48 can draw up to 320mA, (160mA per winding).